# Cannot run rails server cannot locate sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I couldn't find an answer for my issue on Stack Overflow and I think it may be because I installed SQLite3 the wrong way after following a youtube tutorial.

I followed this tutorial to install SQLite https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOJWL3oXDO8&t=176s. I initially installed http://sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3260000.zip under the Precompiled Binaries for Windows section on the SQLite website. I extracted the files then pasted it into C:\sqlite (I changed the name of the folder to sqlite). Then I went to Edit the System Environmental Variables (I just typed it into Cortana search) and then clicked Environmental Variables. I clicked Path, then Edit, then New, then I typed in C:\sqlite.

I ran the following on my windows 10 computer.

$ rails new blog

$ cd blog

$ bundle install

$ rails server

And then it returned the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        17: from D:/Programming Projects/Web Design Projects and Notes/Rails/Rails Learn/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

The thing is, I then tried to delete the C:\sqlite folder and then delete the edit I made in Environmental Variables. Then I ran the following in command line:

$ gem 'sqlite3', git: 'https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby'

It then returned:

ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Unknown command sqlite3,

So now I'm really confused.

Comment: I'm not going to watch a YouTube video to understand what you did, and I doubt anyone else will either, so I suggest including the relevant info from the video in your post. But I can tell you that the command is `gem install sqlite3`, not `gem sqlite3`.

Comment: you should be able to open up a console and run `sqlite3` from the command line. I suspect it's not in your environment path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted everything. Ruby, rails, sqlite. Then I downloaded RailsInstaller and just used that and it worked okay. The first time I tried RailsInstaller, it did some weird thing where it seemed to have had an error. This time it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

`C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby`

Fortunately your system is 64 bits as I do not know solution for the 32 bits.

Download this:

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MSP-Greg/sqlite3-ruby/build/3/job/hhk6ie8gdo545svr/artifacts

And in the folder where you downloaded it open the cmd and run:

`gem install sqlite3-1.3.13.20180326210955-x64-mingw32.gem`

There are shorter ways to do it in the cmd but I have been specific.